# How to fill a list as object field on client side?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the entities `book` and `author`, and there is a many-to-many relationship between them (one book can have many authors, one author can have many books). The book class has a `private List <Author> authors;` field. I pass the list of all authors to the view as model attribute. The view returns an object of the `BbookViewModel`, whose field is a list of selected author ids. How can I add this id to the list when choosing an `option` from a `select` (using thymeleaf)?

`BookController`

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository repository;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/books")  
    private String getAllBooks(Model model)   
    {  
        // some code ...
        model.addAttribute("bookModel", new models.Book());
        model.addAttribute("allAuthors", authorRepository.findAll());
        return "books.html";
    }  
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/books/create", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})  
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationResponse create(@Valid @ModelAttribute models.Book book, BindingResult result)   
    {  
        // ...
    } 
}
```

Part of `books.html`

```
<form id="bookCreationForm" th:action="@{/books/create}" th:object="${bookModel}"
    method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><label th:text="Name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label th:text="Author" /></td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" /*th:field="${}"*/>
                    <option value="0">Select author</option>
                    <option th:each="author : ${allAuthors}" th:value="${author.id}" th:text="${author}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Should I use a multi-select and send the list of ids separately from the book model?

Comment: It would be helpful to see HTML template and controller code.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: I just had to add a `multiple` attribute to the `select` tag. The binding system will find the `authors` field in the class `Book` and link the `List` to the selected values.

```
<form id="bookCreationForm" th:action="@{/books/create}" th:object="${bookModel}"
    method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <!-- some book fields-->
        <tr>
            <td><label th:text="Authors" /></td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="authors" multiple>
                    <option th:each="author : ${allAuthors}" th:value="${author.id}" th:text="${author}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```